# The type or namespace name 'ApplicationUserManager' could not be found

Tags: model-view-controller, google-signin

I have followed to the following article as best I can by Rick Anderson: 
[MVC 5 App with Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and Google OAuth2 Sign-on](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on)

I am trying to get Google Authentication tested and working on my local machine...

Startup.Auth.cs is as follows (exactly as per article this time):

```
// Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);


// Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
// and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
// Configure the sign in cookie
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    }
});

app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```

There error is The type or namespace name 'ApplicationUserManager' could not be found.

Do we have to go creating the ApplicationUserManager? (like described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/18/10499038.aspx

Or better:

Where us ApplicationUserManager?  Is there a nuget package that should have created it?

I read in different places that ApplicationUserManager used to be in IdentityConfig.cs, but IdentityConfig.cs is no longer there if you stick to current nuget packages.

Comment: Too many questions, please make more specific questions.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. I have been following a tutorial but I started the MVC 5 project from VS 2012 with an empty project. I think that the creator of the tutorial used a different template that already contained what I found in NuGet.

It is the following:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out what happened. It apparently "uninstalled" the packages. Once I made sure all four were installed, my red squiggly lines went away, lol.