# The name space 'ApplicationUserManager can be found, are you missing some assembly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have Startup class that does the following, but i keep having this error and dont know how to fix them. How do i solve these errors? i do have the correct assemblies used to the above, if perhaps there are some left out, please do assist me and show me what i have been missing to these existing one i have used on this class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google;
using Owin;
using eNtsaTrainingRegistration.Models;

namespace eNtsaTrainingRegistration.App_Start
{
    public partial class Startup
    {

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to a single instance per request.

            // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);// Cannot be found 'ApplicationUserManager' are you missing some assembly...
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create); // Cannot be found 'ApplicationSignInManager' are you missing some assembly...
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);// Cannot be found 'ApplicationRoleManager' are you missing some assembly...

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            // Configure the sign in cookie
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
            app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

            // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
            // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
            // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
            app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

            // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
            //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
            //    clientId: "",
            //    clientSecret: "");

            //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
            //   consumerKey: "",
            //   consumerSecret: "");

            //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
            //   appId: "",
            //   appSecret: "");

            //app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
            //{
            //    ClientId = "",
            //    ClientSecret = ""
            //});
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Well, where's the `ApplicationUserManager` class defined? Where is the class?

Comment: IdentityConfig.cs

Comment: You can relate your problem with this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525641/the-type-or-namespace-name-applicationusermanager-could-not-be-found/27279435

Comment: Its funny because i do have those libraries installed on my NuGet, i am still getting this issue. Any other option perhaps that might be an impact?